# How to test if I have a working VPN connection?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, vpn, openvpn

I have setup a CentOS 5 OpenVPN server using [this](http://faq.screv.com/sites/screv_faq.nsf/docs/OpenVPN%20CentOS%205%2064bit) howto.

The test client is another CentOS 5, where I have copied `ca.crt`, `client1.crt`, `client1.key` and `client.conf` to.

I don't see any errors when doing

```
openvpn --config client.conf
```

on the client, and I don't see any error messages in the server logs.

`ifconfig` on the client only shows me `eth0` and `lo` and default gateway in `route` haven't been changed to the openvpn's IP address.

**Question**

How do I know if a VPN connection have been established and working?

What command output should I expect?

**Update**

When I look at [this](http://duncanbrown.org/index.php/OpenVPN_With_CentOS) howto, he configure iptable. Should I also do that?

**Update2**

The problem might have been that my test client was a VMware VM. When I try with a bare metal client, I get the `tun0` device.

Why I can't have an OpenVPN connection in a VMware VM is beyond me, but it seams to be the problem I guess.

Comment: try turning up the logging level in the server and client configs.

Comment: Please post your server and client configuration files? And as @Sirex suggested, increate `verb` to `9` and give us the output on client?

Comment: @quanta : it seamed to have been a VMware problem. Apparently openVPN client doesn't work in a VMware VM. When I use the same client files on bare metal, I get a `tun0` device...

Comment: @Sirex : Using a bare metal client seamed to solve the problme instead of using a VMware VM for client...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ifconfig on the client only shows me eth0 and lo and default gateway
>   in route haven't been changed to the openvpn's IP address.

It means that your VPN connection is not working. Please give us the output on client and logs on the server.

Comment: ok. I have now updated the post with the client and server logs.

Comment: Done an update. Might have been a VMware problem...

Answer (score 0):

**OpenVPN** generally uses **UDP**, which is **stateless**. This means, that unless you have a **keepalive** option configured, it can have a tun interface up forever, even if there is no connection at all.

To be able to see if the connection is up, enable keepalive and do a ping test every now and then. Put in you servers config:

> keepalive 10 120